# OpenAPI Generator works from command line but not from Gradle Plugin

Tags: gradle, openapi, openapi-generator

I want to generate the client stubs for my Flutter/Dart application for an internal API written in OpenAPI 3. The server itself was generated using the same API spec with the Maven plugin `org.openapitools.openapi-generator-maven-plugin`.

When I try to generate the Dart client stubs in this way via the command line it works fine:

```
java -cp openapi-generator-cli-5.1.1.jar org.openapitools.codegen.OpenAPIGenerator generate -i ./api_spec/api.json -g dart --enable-post-process-file
```

But I want to put it in a gradle build as part of the Flutter application, so I followed the instructions and created this `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "org.openapi.generator" version "5.1.1"
}

openApiGenerate {
    generatorName = "dart"
    inputSpec = "$rootDir/api_spec/api.json"
    outputDir = "$rootDir/../api"
    apiPackage = "mypackage.api"
    modelPackage = "mypackage.api"
}
```

However, this does not generate the client stubs. (I even tried changing language to see where the problem is, and the effect is the same). I get a bunch of errors like the following, which seem to indicate that for some reason it is expecting a Swagger 2.0 file instead of an OpenAPI 3.x file.

```
> Task :openApiGenerate FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':openApiGenerate'.
> There were issues with the specification. The option can be disabled via validateSpec (Maven/Gradle) or --skip-validate-spec (CLI).
   | Error count: 72, Warning count: 0
  Errors:
        -attribute paths.'/subscriber/{id}/device'(post).[id].type is missing
        -attribute openapi is unexpected
        -attribute servers is unexpected
        -attribute swagger is missing
        -attribute components is unexpected
```

Is there any way to fix this, or to specify the OpenAPI version explicitly?

I even tried to set `validateSpec = false` but it does not make any difference, the flag is ignored and I still get the same output.

Comment: Could you post a redacted version of your JSON API file? That would be helpful to reproduce the issue. Thank you!

Comment: Suggest a fix
"Quick fix": Move the alternative Option skipValidateSpec next to validateSpec in the description of options in Gradle plugin's README.adoc. Thus, users new to the plugin will see at once, that there is an alternative option that works. Ref: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/9815